# How to get reference of GridGroupingControl through GridTableControl?

Tags: c#, winforms, syncfusion

I am developing a windows application in which i used GridGroupingControl (Syncfusion Control). In the code i used `void TableControl_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)` event, in the event i was getting "GridTableControl" reference of GGC using : `GridTableControl grdControl = sender as GridTableControl;` but i also want the reference of GridGroupingControl to which GridTableControl belong, like :

```
GridTableControl grdControl = sender as GridTableControl;
GridGroupingControl ggc = (grdControl.Parent) as GridGroupingControl;
```

But here ggc is null.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can access Grid Grouping Control from TableControl by using `GridGroupingControl ggc = (grdControl.GroupingControl) as GridGroupingControl` instead of `GridGroupingControl ggc = (grdControl.Parent) as GridGroupingControl`.

Here is the code that you need to handle in MouseMove Event:

```
GridTableControl grdControl = sender as GridTableControl;
GridGroupingControl ggc = (grdControl.GroupingControl) as GridGroupingControl;
```

I hope the above code will help you achieve your result.